# Div pushing down the div next to it

Tags: html, css

I have div which pushes down the other div, 
I want div "Coupon_right" and all of its content to be to the right top next to the image. At the moment there is a big space above.

You can see the div with all of the text in is pushed down,

[image]

My HTML is :

```
<div id="coupon">

<?php

echo 

'<div id="coupon_wrapper">' .

    '<div id="coupon_image">' .

        '<img src="images/stores'. "/" . $row['storename'] .'.png">' . 

    '</div>' .

    '<div id="coupon_expire_date">' .

        "hi".

    '</div>'.

    '<div id="coupon_right">' .

        '<div id="design_coupon_title">' .

            '<a href="http://www.' . $row['coupon_link'] . '">' . ucfirst($row['coupon_title']) . '</a>' . 

        '</div>' .

    '</div>' .

'</div>' .

"<br>";

?>

</div>
```

Here is my CSS :

```
#coupon_wrapper {
    /* position: absolute; */

}

#coupon {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-right:5px;
    width:450px;
    height:120px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    /*
    border:1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    */
}

#coupon:hover {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
}


#coupon_image {
    width:130px;
    height:80px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;

    border:1px solid black ;
}

#coupon_expire_date {
    width:130px;
    height:20px;
    position: relative;

    border:1px solid black;
}

#coupon img {
    display: block;
    max-width:120px;
    max-height:70px;
    margin:0 auto;
    /* VERTICAL ALIGN */
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#coupon_right {
    width:290px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:70px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}

#design_coupon_title {
    text-align: center;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid black;
    right:0;
}
```

EDIT :

For the site to work, #coupon wrapper has to be position absolute instead of #coupon

This is what it looks like with all child positions removed and no "display:..." used as these could be causing problems.

[image]

Here is the updated : CSS

```
#coupon_wrapper {
    position: absolute; 
}

#coupon {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-right:5px;
    width:450px;
    height:120px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    /*
    border:1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    */
}

#coupon:hover {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
}

#coupon_image {
    width:130px;
    height:80px;
    background-color: #fff;

    border:1px solid black ;
}

#coupon_expire_date {
    width:130px;
    height:20px;

    border:1px solid black;
}

#coupon img {
    max-width:120px;
    max-height:70px;
    margin:0 auto;
    /* VERTICAL ALIGN */
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#coupon_right {
    width:290px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:70px;
}

#design_coupon_title {
    text-align: center;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid black;
    right:0;
}

#coupon a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}
```

Thankyou for the suggestions so far, however none of them seem to fix the problem, Im thinking the coupon_expire_date which is causing the problem.

Comment: Please do not post PHP code. Post the actual HTML. There is no reason to double-space the code either.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, i found the best solution was to simply put a div around all content on the left and float it left,

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a start:**
*can't be sure because I'm not with your images.*

- remove the `#coupon img` CSS rule
- add `#coupon_image` and replace `#coupon_right`

```css
#coupon_image {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width:120px;
    max-height:70px;
    margin:0 auto;
    float: left;
}

#coupon_right {
    width:290px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:70px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
```

here's a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/warkentien2/jgmnc9ue/
what else is missing?

Comment: this doesn't do anything, just messes up the arrangement of all the other divs

Comment: I was being fast, you obviously will only pass it the the 2 div's in question.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: it must be conflicting with so many other rules. like `#coupon img {
    display: block; }` (which is the opposite rule for the exact same element)

Comment: I just removed them all and it still doesnt move, am i correct in saying that the wrapper should be position absolute and all of the child elements should be relative ?

Comment: You don't have to position anything absolute. Position: fixed = position sticks to the screen (a.k.a. window), absolute = position sticks to the entire html document, relative = position sticks to parent element. <- so normally you'll use relative. However, to use `left, top,` positioning rules, you need to specify a position (whatever type you wish)

Answer (score 0):

[Pen](http://codepen.io/ph110293/pen/MewPej)

```css
#coupon_wrapper {
    /* position: absolute; */

}

#coupon {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-right:5px;
    width:450px;
    height:120px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: relative;
    /*
    border:1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    */
}

#coupon:hover {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
}


#coupon_image {
    width:130px;
    height:80px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
position: absolute;
top:12px;
    border:1px solid black ;
}

#coupon_expire_date {
    width:130px;
    height:20px;
    position: absolute;
Top:94px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-top:0px;
}

#coupon img {
    display: block;
    max-width:120px;
    max-height:70px;
    margin:0 auto;
    /* VERTICAL ALIGN */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#coupon_right {
    width: 290px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    left: 35%;
}

#design_coupon_title {
    text-align: center;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid black;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="coupon">

<?php

echo 

'<div id="coupon_wrapper">' .

    '<div id="coupon_image">' .

        '<img src="images/stores'. "/" . $row['storename'] .'.png">' . 

    '</div>' .

    '<div id="coupon_expire_date">' .

        "hi".

    '</div>'.

    '<div id="coupon_right">' .

        '<div id="design_coupon_title">' .

            '<a href="http://www.' . $row['coupon_link'] . '">' . ucfirst($row['coupon_title']) . '</a>' . 

        '</div>' .

    '</div>' .

'</div>' .

"<br>";

?>

</div>
```

Since you are positioning outer(coupon) div relative, child divs should be positioned absolute.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion, I have applied this to the site and it does work but for multiple coupons to display, position absolute must be on #coupon_wrapper not #coupon, and this then causes your solution to break, please would you have a look at the edited CSS i have posted ? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Note the commenting (`<!--   -->`) between the two inline block divs - this removes the space between the blocks - if you want a space between them, just take out the comment, and they will be separated by a few pixels.

```css
#coupon_wrapper {
  /* position: absolute; */
}
#coupon {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  /*
    border:1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    */
}
#coupon:hover {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
#coupon_image {
  width: 130px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#coupon_expire_date {
  width: 130px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#coupon img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 120px;
  max-height: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#coupon_right {
  width: 290px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#design_coupon_title {
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="coupon">
  <div id="coupon_image"></div><!--
  --><div id="coupon_right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #coupon_wrapper {
            /* position: absolute; */
        }

        #coupon {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            width: 450px;
            height: 120px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 3px;
            position: absolute;
            /*
        border:1px solid black;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        */
        }

            #coupon:hover {
                border: 1px solid #aaa;
            }


        #coupon_image {
            width: 130px;
            height: 80px;
            background-color: #fff;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #coupon_expire_date {
            width: 130px;
            height: 20px;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #coupon img {
            display: inline;
            max-width: 120px;
            max-height: 70px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            /* VERTICAL ALIGN */
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }

        #coupon_right {
            width: auto;
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: auto;
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            float: right;
        }

        #coupon_left {
            width: auto;
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: auto;
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
        }

        #design_coupon_title {
            text-align: center;
            height: 40px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            right: 0;
        }

        #coupon_design {
           position:absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="coupon_wrapper">
        <div id="coupon_design">
            <div id="coupon_left">
                <div id="coupon_image">
                    Image Value
                </div>
                <div id="coupon_expire_date">
                    Hi expiry date
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="coupon_right">
                <div id="design_coupon_title">
                    Right side value
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Bootstrap for this instead of writing own CSS classes. That will make your life easier. The following link will guide you to the grid example, which addresses to your question. You can divide the browser as you want and in responsive manner also.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic